# Android Custom xml drawable color not visible

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable, android-styles

I have made two custom xml drawable of shape line as below:

1. **divider_line_ok.xml**

   ```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="line">
           <size
               android:width="150dp"
               android:height="1dp"></size>

           <solid android:color="#000000"></solid>

   </shape>
   ```

2.**divider_line_error.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">
    <size
        android:width="150dp"
        android:height="3dp"></size>

    <solid android:color="#ec0000"></solid>
</shape>
```

I am using these two drawable in another custom drawable **edittext_divider_line.xml** based on the property **state_activated** like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/divider_line_error" android:state_activated="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/divider_line_ok" />
</selector>
```

And then we have set this drawable as background in a style like below:

```
<style name="divider_line_style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittext_divider_line</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

And finally used this style in an ImageView:

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/xyz_divider"
        style="@style/divider_line_style"
       />
```

So that when we call `view.setActivated(true)` method for this imageView, the view should change according to the states that are defined in **edittext_divider_line.xml** i.e. `@drawable/divider_line_error`.

When I change the activation state to true, I can see the height of the view changes from 1dp to 3dp but I can not see the color that I have set in the drawables that are set for the two states in any of the activated states.

In short, The color is not being used from any of the drawables. Just the height changes. Please help me find the issue.

P.S. Please ask in comments in case anything is not clear.

Comment: downvoter please specify the reason for downvote

Answer (score 0):

May be using other property:

```
android:state_active
android:state_focused
...
```

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html